# "at which time" vs. "at what time"

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I am confused with the grammar here. Which is grammatically correct?

- > At which time will you call me?
- > At what time will you call me?

And why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this sort of context *which* usually refers to a choice between previously defined alternatives. For instance:

> I have some time free at 9:30, at 11:00 and at 1:30. At **which** time will you call me?

*What* is used when there are no such previously defined alternatives.

> I have no appointments tomorrow, so I can talk at any time. At **what** time will you call me?

Both, however, are quite formal. Most people would say, simply

> When will you call me?

Answer (score 7):

I believe that though *at which time* is not grammatically wrong, you should stick with *At what time will you call me?* or even better: ***What time will you call (me) (again)?***

Another idiomatic phrase is: ***When will you call?***

Generally, when you ask a *which* question, it implies a choosing from choices. Asking for time usually an open question, so using *what* is better.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add that "at which time" can also be used to introduce a non-restrictve relative clause:

> The museum will remain closed until 6:00am, at which time we will open the doors to visitors.

Substituting "at what time" in place of "at which time" would not be appropriate in this sentence.